# Web app not working on IPad but works on desktop browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, browser

I am creating a web application that runs on an ipad using JQuery, CSS and HTML, when i test my application on a web browser everything works perfectly, but when i access the web app through the ipads browser all the windows look the same but none of the functionality is there. I have no idea why because i have all the .js files imported into the .html files and all the functionality works on the safari and fire on the desktop.... It is as if the web app on the ipad is ignoring all my .js files!

here is a picture of my files and i can add code if anybody wants it

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why the functionality would not be working on the ipad?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why it's not working, but you might be interested in trying one of the following in order to see what's going on:

- weinre (WEb INspector REmote): http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/
- Adobe Shadow - http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/shadow.html

What these do is let you have an inspector like FireBug for stuff that's going through a mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that it does actually load your js files, but because of some error in your code, the js just stops running. If I remember correctly there are some developer tools available on the iPad which you can turn on via de settings app. You can also look at your web server logs to see if, when accessing via the iPad, the js files are also requested. If they are, it is most likely a js error somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the web pages locally on the device or remotely?

If they are being run locally, then make sure that the JS fies are actually copied into the application bundle.

By default they for some reason stuck into 'Compile Sources' and not copied as is.

In XCode4, click on your project in the left pane, and select `Build Phases` in the right pane.
Under `Copy Bundle Resources`, make sure that your js files are there - if not, add them using the '+'.

Comment: No the application is being run remotely, I think i have found the problem. I have a duplicate folder with the same names as in the js folder in another project in the overall same folder so the ipad is mixing up these two folders as all the names are the same so it should just be a matter now of changing all the names of the files